# What is Hash#count?

Tags: ruby, hash, count

I was playing with IRB (Ruby 2.5.1) when I noticed this:

```
irb(main):020:0> h 
=> {3=>4, :aaa=>false} 
irb(main):021:0> h.count 
=> 2
```

However, this method doesn't exist in [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html).

A quick test shows that `hsh.count` gives the same result as `hsh.keys.count`, and `Hash.ancestors` contains `Enumerable`.

What exactly is Hash#count?

Comment: `obj.method(:count).owner` can be useful.

Comment: Further to @muistooshort's comment, `obj.method(:count) #=> #<UnboundMethod: Hash(Enumerable)#count>` is sufficient (that is, without `.owner` tacked on), as the owner (here `Enumerable`) is shown parenthetically along with `Hash` if the owner is not `obj.class`. This is the same as `Hash.instance_method(:count)`.

Comment: @muistooshort, you should make that an answer, as it provides an important tool for locating methods generally.

Comment: `count` is documented somewhere since an instance of `Hash` responds to it. It would be better to say that the docs for instance methods defined on `Hash` do not include `count`.

Comment: (From the link you provided) It's always worth checking the sidebar heading **Included Modules**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have gotten most of the way there... it's [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).

Technically, `hsh.keys.count` is counting the keys, and `hsh.count` is counting the *pairs* (as would be yielded by `hsh.each`), but those are identical values in practice, because each pair has a unique key.

Comment: However `hsh.keys.count` will perform better than `hsh.count` due to the fact that `Array#count` without any arguments is the same a `length`. That being said `Hash#length` (`Hash#size`) would be the most performant in this case as it does not require the transformation to an `Array` of keys first